# SQL Server 2016 CTRP3.2 Report Viewer is missing a JavaScript method

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportviewer, sql-server-2016

Using SQL Server 2016 CTP3.2 Report Viewer (13.0.800.111), only the toolbar is shown.

[image: chrome Sample]

It looks like a Power BI method is missing.

[image: JavaScript Error]

Also, will there be a NuGet for Report Viewer?

Comment: OnPowerBIFeaturesRelease is still missing in CTP3.3 (13.0.1000.25)

Comment: This is **STILL** an issue with the released version :( Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=13.0.1601.5&Name=ViewerScript:5394

Comment: Checking on this.

Comment: Ticket: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3101522/report-viewer-2016-broken-v-13-0-1601-5

Comment: NuGet for report viewer 13: `Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview`

Answer (score 1):

Just ran across this thread. The question: "will there be a NuGet for Report Viewer?" -- Yes, look out for a NuGet version of 2016 based report viewer controls this month (September).

Note that the controls will not expose the PowerBI method described here.

Comment: Ace. We are just looking to do an in place upgrade from ReportViewer Local Mode SSRS 2014 (12) to 2016 (13). We are running in Azure so have use the redis cache and legacy security model.
I'd love to see a git repository that has a sample project for the ReportViewer 2016 in the latest ASP (or 4.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

To overcome broken report viewer you have to purge its files v.13.0.1601.5 from GAC and use **updated ones from nuget package**: [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview/) (version 130.1700.305, published 2016-09-20).

> - Make sure you have the latest version of [SQL Server Data Tools installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501). Earlier versions incorrectly GAC'ed certain libraries that will cause issues.
> - **The Report Viewer Control is designed to be included in projects via nuget.** It's not a good idea to add the libraries to the GAC.
> - If deploying the control on an intranet site make sure that the page is targeting HTML5.

More info at this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/blob/master/Docs/Get-Started-With-RVC.md#next-steps---read

It works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sample of the missing javascript method "OnPowerBIFeaturesRelease" in localmode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was able to avoid this script error with the 2016 Report Viewer. Try adding these missing references before the Report Viewer definition.

Note: This will only work if your Report Server is on the same domain as your Website. You can also manually copy the files into your project and then serve them locally if your on a separate domain.

[image]