# Is there a new Report Viewer Runtime for SQL 2016?

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a new Report Viewer runtime for SQL 2016?  I get the new report viewer UI when I log into the SSRS Reports manager, but, if I embed those reports in a website, it requires the Report Viewer redistributable, and the most recent one I can find is from 2015, which I assume will not have the new UI.

Thanks!

Ryan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't, at least not yet. 
The ReportViewer installed by SQL-Server 2016 is v12, which is the 2015 Viewer.

Also, it seems SSRS 2016 uses a RS:ReportHost tag, wheras < 2016 used to use the rs:ReportViewer tag.

---

**Edit:**
But now you can download the preview here:
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview/130.1700.305

Rename

```
microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol
.webforms.preview.130.1700.305.nupkg
```

to

```
microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol
.webforms.preview.130.1700.305.nupkg.zip
```

and then unzip it. 
It still is using .NET Framework 4.0.

I got it working, here:
https://github.com/ststeiger/ReportViewerWrapper/tree/master/Embedded2016
Just in the nick of time, had to fix a nasty bug with WordOpenXML export. 
In versions of ReportViewer < 2016, you can't print a Word 2007+ (WordOpenXML) document when in landscape-format).
Switching to ReportViewer 2016 Preview solved this.

There appears to be a bug in ReportViewer, when you export to word. 
Vertical alignment is not center by default, in Visual Studio it is (old bug). 
And merging the last row of a table in a word-document will result in a garbage-layout - when pageformat = landscape (new bug).

If you put this formula into the footer

```
=System.Convert.ToString(Globals!PageNumber) + "/" + System.Convert.ToString(Globals!TotalPages)
```

you always get 1/1 in Word.
 
If you use

```
=Globals!PageNumber & "/" & Globals!TotalPages
```

then it works correctly... (old bug)

Comment: Can you provide a source with any documentation for that tag change to RS:ReportHost?

Comment: You find it on ReportServer.aspx in the SSRS 2016 ReportServer install directory.

Answer (score 3):

There is a latest nuget package of Report Viewer 2016 *Preview*: [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview/) (version 130.1700.305, published 2016-09-20).

And read carefully this page to setup it properly: https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/blob/master/Docs/Get-Started-With-RVC.md#next-steps---read

Comment: There is already an official documentation, "Getting started with the ReportViewer 2016 control": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt764770.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Nuget package is now no longer in Preview, so you can get Report Viewer 2016 as detailed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started

If required, SQL Server Data Tools will install the latest Report Viewer control:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked inside 
`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\` ?
When we upgraded our v12 to v13, that we had Power BI issues :

[SQL Server 2016 CTRP3.2 Report Viewer is missing a JavaScript method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444176/sql-server-2016-ctrp3-2-report-viewer-is-missing-a-javascript-method)

The drawback is Microsoft haven't exposed the ReporViewer controls as a redistributable runtime package (yet)