# SSRS 2016 Report Viewer Control

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2016

We are looking at installing SSRS 2016. We currently use ReportViewer Control 11 (2012). Do we need to upgrade to ReportViewer Control 12 (2015) in order for us to view reports?

I'm assuming there isn't any 2016 version yet.

Just want to make sure all is possible if we install 2016 version of SSRS.

Comment: I haven't tried doing anything yet. Right now i'm just researching for an upcoming upgrade. So far right now from the research i've done i'm understanding that the 2016 report viewer control is not released yet and that the 2015 version should work fine with the 2016 version of SSRS though there will be some features that do not work..... but the core should work.d

Comment: install the newest sql data tools on your computer and iis server and re-reference them in your project.  but my old report files never upgraded and have this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599611/ssrs-report-files-rdl-how-to-upgrade-to-latest

Comment: It would be nice if a NuGet package is released: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444176/sql-server-2016-ctrp3-2-report-viewer-is-missing-a-javascript-method

Answer (score 3):

SSRS 2016 Report Designer uses a new 2016 schema definition for the rdls that is *NOT* supported by the v12 control:

> http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition

So if you Upgrade your SSRS to 2016, and you have upgraded your designer tools and you are using the report viewer control in your own web app (which you must be or you wouldn't have asked right) Then you will have to use the v13 report viewer.

> If your RDLs are not edited with the latest designer tools, the v12 report viewer should still be able to render them, though I have not tested this scenario against the latest CTP

---

The v12 report viewer is backwards compatible with 2005, 2008, 2010 and of course the 2012 schema definitions (which is used by the 2014/2015 report designers).

So if your team has upgraded to VS 2015 Update 3, with the latest SQL Server Data Tools, then you will start to see 2016 report definitions popping up as they get edited.

> previous versions of SQL Data Tools would only upgrade the RDL definition when you used one of the new features, this new version seems to upgrade them regardless

---

There is no 'official' client runtime download for the v13 report viewer yet, you will have to extract the necessary dlls from the GAC from the server with SSRS 2016 running on it, or from a development machine with the latest Data Tools installed. If you run into issues have a look at the ReportViewer.aspx file in the SSRS 2016 Web App Folder for the latest syntax changes.

Comment: Any word on when the V13 report viewer control will be "officially released"?

Comment: The v13 is in preview, you can get the latest builds from this NuGet feed:  Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Pre‌​view

Comment: The 2016 version of the Report Viewer control is now available for WinForms and WebForms. (27.07.2017)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has released an early preview of the Report Viewer 13 controls on nuget. I have tested it out and found it to be working just as well as the viewer directly on the report server.

The only issue I have ran into is that hidden parameters now seem to leave a blank table cell in the toolbar rather than shifting the non-hidden parameters over.

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview/

Using the report viewer control:

> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=827676

Comment: As this is a preview feed, be aware that there are volatile components. As we approach release this feed will become more stable, for a production deployment I would not recommend using it just yet, but absolutely try it out and post if you have any issues.

Comment: We are actually using it on a production site right now without many issues. Worst we have run into is that the parameters do not reposition themselves when a parameter is hidden, leaving an odd blank slot. Our internal staff would rather deal with that compared to not having a simple print feature.

Answer (score 2):

The 2016 version of the Report Viewer control is now available for WinForms and WebForms. [(27.07.2017)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/07/27/updated-report-viewer-control-now-generally-available/)  The NuGet package is available at [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/) and [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms/) but the MVC version is still pending.