# SSRS report files (.rdl) how to upgrade to latest?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, bids, ssrs-2016

I have been using Visual Studio 2010 for Reporting Services projects, with a SQL server 2012 reporting services back-end.   To display the report we went from version 10,to 11 with the Reporting viewer in asp.net like so with no problems.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer03" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                    Font-Size="8pt" Height="400px" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="950px">
                    <ServerReport ReportPath="/ReportsProgram_YEAR8/Rpt03_SurveyCountsByLanguageMethod" 
                        ReportServerUrl="http://sql2012a/ReportServer_SQL2016" />
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Installing SQL Server 2016, and reporting services, and SQL Data Tools 2015 all went well.

i can change the version of the assembly above to 11.0 and the report will still render, fine the old looking way.

But when using Visual Studio 2015 or SQL Data Tools 2015 opening the old project file or individual .rdl files, did not prompt to upgrade like I am seeing on the internet.  As far as i remember there was no SQL Data Tools 2013 so I never had a chance to upgrade.

Anyway looking inside the report files, its obvious the xml tag has not been upgraded.  Not only that there the report has issues. (see screen shot below)

[image]

Now I have created a new report from scratch and the drop down does work for export and print, but the area below the toolbar with the two drop downs is still present with print, cancel and done.  I have upgraded my ajaxtoolkit and everything.  I have no choice but to continue to use SQL Reporting Services 2012 (very sad)

Can anyone shed any light as to the issues?

Comment: FYI if i go right to the reporting services link(not using a viewer) all works well.

Comment: did you try using IE?

Comment: ie or edge even prior and post windows 10 no difference

Comment: i have now noticed that Visual Studio 2015 update 3 revision 3 OR Microsoft Data Tools latest update.  Now when i double click an old SSRS report.  It changes the top xml tag to the newer version, and adds a new section for parameters on the bottom (as they are now shown at the top for odd reasons as well as the Report Data viewer) section and Visual Studio 2010 will not render the report.  not much of an xml upgrade but it upgraded it.  But still looks like the screen shot above, all messed up unless i use the sharepoint portal of SSRS

Comment: 1] This is .rdl file & not the .rdlc ? 
2] You are viewing report in .net application or report manager\share point ?

Comment: visual studio 2015 "upgrades the reports" now after the latest service pack, but i still get the horrid output seen above in the screenshot above using version 13.0 of the report viewer

Comment: the output above is in .net application <reportviewer.   It looks fine in the report manager\share point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using report viewer 13 for working with SSRS 2016. It is available on nuget as a preview release.

`Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview`

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/09/23/embed-paginated-reports-into-asp-net-web-apps-using-the-report-viewer-2016-control/

If SQL Server Data Tools or SQL Server Management Studio for SQL 2016 is installed, make sure it’s updated to the latest version. Earlier versions of SSDT incorrectly gac’ed certain dlls which conflict with the Report Viewer Control. You may need to manually delete the V13 dll's  from \windows\assembly\gac_msil to permanently remove them.

**How to uninstall**

gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

If you get Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/873195

Comment: if i uninstall this file im my reporting services server it would be scary.  I will setup another server to test this with.  This server had sql 2012, and went right to 2016 RTM and then had the problem.  I will have to use a test VM to do this.  What is the latest modified date of the correct dll's listed above?

Comment: i almost certain this is the answer thank you. but i have to be careful on my production server.

Comment: if i uninstall them how do i get them back in. NuGet only installs locally  gacultil /i ?

Comment: more info

https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/blob/master/Docs/Get-Started-With-RVC.md#next-steps---read

Comment: can we start a chat?

Comment: sadly this did not work

ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQgPeUxwtjVsBXcYI8LxY478uZc7vF1VZC4NLF7ZwHVXh1TcjzJC2VvkDbm…:45 Uncaught Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: method
/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=BackImage…1.5&Color=%23ECE9D8&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.toolbar_bk.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 404 (Not Found) - so not only does the toolbar not work now, i still get the odd area below it, only thing i did not do was reboot. just restarted services

Comment: detailed report to github https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/issues/5

Comment: You wouldn't need to uninstall these assemblies from the GAC on your reporting server, just on your web application host. Also, only uninstall them if the nuget package does not work.

Comment: i have a iis VM, and a SQL server VM, now your saying do this on IIS? even though when i compile my application all the new preview dll files are in the \bin directory - well i got this message  

Microsoft (R) .NET 
Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications
Pending references:
              SCHEME: <WINDOWS_INSTALLER>  ID: <MSI>  DESCRIPTION : <Windows Ins
taller>
Number of assemblies uninstalled = 0
Number of failures = 0

Comment: well you lead me to the right direction, i just installed the september version of SSDT ONE THE WEB server and its fine

Comment: brad ,,, now take a look at this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757833/asp-net-webforms-site-using-ssrs-2012-reportviewer-loading-disappears-and-times

Comment: now all ssrs 2012 reports are in conflict and are down Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'

Comment: i was able to stop the errors, moving them to a different domain.  hopefully the business will accept that as one website cannot accept both httpHandlers , virtual directory, with a different application pool or not.

Comment: i know this is an old question.  But here is what the problem was. 

1) i needed the pre-release
2) the SSDT update actually needed to be installed on my IIS Server VM, not the SQL Server (although its needed on both)

eventually they fixed all these issues and it works fine now